# Image in loading from specified path

Tags: java, swing

When I am giving absolute path of image means from my project `scr` directory it loads the image but when I am trying to load image from specified path or relative path then it shows null error, it doesn't read image.
i have get path using `JFilechooser` directory specifically, it only display `.jpg` image and give list of files to File type and stored one by one image in string variable and then want to load image using that variable.

My code:

```
final String fpath;
final File dir = new File("");
final JFileChooser file;
file = new JFileChooser();
file.setCurrentDirectory(dir);
file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
file.showOpenDialog(contentPane);
final File[] lofFile = file.getCurrentDirectory().listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    if (lofFile[i].toString().substring(lofFile[i].toString().lastIndexOf(".") + 1).equals("jpg")) {
        az = lofFile[i].toString();
    }
}

private BufferedImage bg;
bg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(az));
```

Throws this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Any help please?

Comment: The JVM **never** prints "shows error."  What is the _actual_ error message?

Comment: post code where you enter on "Open" dialog button

Comment: @Sean Bright - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)   is an error, sorry i have just write that to highlight.

Comment: If you knew the names of the files inside a given directory, then you can simply use this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187181/1057230). Hopefully this might help :-) Though I doubt, `getClass().getResource()` will work in this situation, since this is used to get the location relative to the `.class/package`. So what if your `.class` file is in `Drive E` and you are trying to access images from `Drive F`, you need to device a way to convert the relative path in such a way, that it can move to the image file, relative to the location of `.class` file, IMHO.

Comment: @nIcEcOw - but i exactly dont know all files, so that's why i have written up this long code to fetch up file from choosen directory.

Comment: @user2659972 : Please have a look at [DirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html), there is small code snippet, which can help you know the names of each files.

Comment: @nIcEcOw - i have solved that using below solution. by the way thank u so much because you have told me to directly pass File Type as an argument.

Comment: @user2659972 : Please have a look at this code [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ncqkcj6hyvm78u/DirectoryFiles.java), here you specify the folder which contains the images, and it loads all images from the folder and display them on the `JPanel`. I hope you can modify this according to your needs :-)

Comment: @ niCe cOw - sir if there is any simple example of it then please help me, i have tried ArrayList<String> = lofFile but it doesn't work. also tried List<String> but not work.

Comment: @user2659972 : Please find the [simplest example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/75h5u9effv6ph6r/LoadImageFromDirectory.java), though do change the directory path, according to your `FileSystem` (mean to say, as to where your images are on the hard disk). I hope this will help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class#getResource` is not for loading files from the file system. *Maybe* `ImageIO.read(az)` will work.

But you get a `File` object from the `JFileChooser`. Use it and you have no problem at all. Don't do any String manipulation on filenames if there is no reason for it. Filtering for a specific suffix is not a reason.

Comment: no its not working it need File type argument. it only read File Type argument data.

Comment: yes that's right, after using directly File Type variable as argument with ImageIO.read then it works smoothly and easily, thank you so much.

Comment: @ nIcE cOw - sir i want add one more facility in this code is that if user click button then next image should be loaded in image object, if you just give me guidance then i am so thankful to you.