# JLabel to an Image

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

Can anyone tell me why (by giving me the code) to make the image Dots replace with JLabel Hi
so Dots shows up.  All I am getting right now is the words Hi.

```java
public class Memory extends JPanel {     
ImageIcon Dots = new ImageIcon("Dots.jpg");
private JLabel Hi = new JLabel("Hi");
//ImageIcon Dots = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Dots.jpg"));

Memory(){   
    Hi.setIcon(Dots);
    Hi.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    this.add(Hi);
}
}
```

Comment: variable/members within a class should start with a LowerCase letter. Regarding your problem, is your image `Dots.jpg` path correct? It is at the same level as your class `Memory`?

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). Though if you doing it manually see the last link in that answer. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Or you can take some help from this answer of mine, regarding [set Icon for JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187181/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a folder inside your "src" folder (the folder containing all your .java classes/code) and then put your *.jpg icons there. Then try something like this

```
hi.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/Dots.jpg")));
```

Assuming that the folder's name you created it's "resources".

Comment: I tried doing what nivde92 suggested. It says, Applet not initialized.

Comment: It worked?.
I had an extra folder inside resources called "jpg", check the code now, it shoud work.

Comment: I'm confused. It says applet not initialized and this error at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: could you upload a screen shot from the folders you had inside your project?

Comment: i have the screenshots, but how to i upload them to this website

Comment: try uploading to another website and then just share the link

Comment: basically-  the src folder. in the src folder is the resources folder. in the resources folder is the jpg folder. in the jpg folder is the image shortcut, Dots.jpg

Comment: hmm image shorcut? put the actual image on the folder